# Kosher Cheese without a posted hechsher

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, dairy, hechsher-certification

I live in a remote area of Canada and don't have access to a kosher market to buy cheese. There are many European imports in the local super, and I was wondering if there is a list of cheeses which are kosher without a printed hechsher from EU or elsewhere (the UK, Australia, etc). From my time in Europe, I found that many communities had lists of kosher products one could buy in the super without a printed hechsher.

Thanks.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/does-cheese-without-a-hekhsher-tref-dishes

Comment: You might want to try the [London Beth Din](http://www.kosher.org.uk/intro.htm). If any of the products are from the UK or surrounding areas, you should be able to find it on their "Kosher Product Search". If not, you can always call them and see what they know.

Comment: Yossi, welcome to the site and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site — and find the elusive kosher cheese!

Comment: See Mpinini haRav p197 where R. Schachter discusses R. Soloveitchik's view on vegetable rennet cheese, which he allowed his students to eat.

Comment: If you can identify kosher parmesan that tastes good, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: cheese is special, because even if you know all the ingredients that went into it, if there wasnt a mashgiach present we dont eat it. its a Takanat Hachamim. so even if you know that there is no animal rennet, for example, we still dont eat that cheese

Comment: @Vram, Welcome to Judaism.SE! I converted your answer to a comment because it doesn't address the question, which is asking for a list of cheeses. Please consider registering your account, which will give you access to more of the site's features, including the ability to leave comments like this one on others' posts.

Comment: I presume you are asking about hard cheeses or slices or blocks, because you should not have difficulty finding some cream cheeses and cottage cheeses with hasgachot.  (As for kosher Parmesan, Miller's makes a grated Parmesan in a shaker container that can be refrigerated and lasts for ever  (or until Pesach, when you might want to get a new one!)

Comment: OK, here's either a comment or answer:  Check out this website that lists all kinds of cheeses in the USA.  Surely some must make it up north:  http://www.kcheese.com/US.htm

Answer (score 4):

Per http://www.chabad.gr/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/66080/jewish/Kosher-products-list.htm:

> Cheese: TYRAS-OLYMPUS all cheeses; TERRA AEOLICA (ΑΙΟΛΙΚΗ ΓΗ) (Lesvos) feta cheeses. (Supervised by Rabbi Silver - Kosher Technical Konsultants)  Note: It is not Chalav Israel.

Comment: Not _chalav Yisrael_ but kosher? Why, does Greece have laws like America, and rely on _Rav Moshe_'s ruling? Or is feta like butter? +1 anyway, nice find.

Comment: Do not know, however Rabbi Silver from Kosher Technical Konsultants can be contacted at 215-745-3773 or via Email at raismd@koshertechnicalkonsultants.org

Comment: (Hm, no, feta's being like butter wouldn't suffice, as I see that [Olympus](http://www.olympusdairy.com/products.php) sells many kinds of cheese.)